# How do I send live, real-time notifications to authenticated users in a nodejs web application?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, real-time

I am building a web application that involves user notifications, follows, forum feeds, likes and more.

I want to send users live notifcations, like if someone sent them a follow request or a message.

I also would like to see the like buttons and forum replies update in realtime without the users having to navigate from or refresh the page.

I thought about polling the server, but I don't think this is a good idea.

I am thinking websockets may be a solution, but I could be wrong. I was under the impression that websockets do not handle authentification very well.

Ia there a free solution out there I can use to implement these features? How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Pusher](https://github.com/pusher) offers free accounts.
Since you're using Node, you'll want to use their JS library, [pusher-js](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js)

Comment: I don't know how I can use Pusher with JWT authentication? The docs are not real clear on it. How do I send a JWT over with Pusher?

Comment: I haven't used JWT, but my understanding of it is that the JWT token is just a normal JSON object with a cryptographically-signed data value. If that's the case, I would guess that you could just pass the JWT into Pusher as you would any other kind of auth token.

FWIW: The Pusher docs have a page specifically about implementing auth on both the server and client sides of an app.
https://www.pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authenticating-users